# Hibernate save relational table

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have a database with the following table structures...

> The *Customer* table has two columns : id, name.
>
> The *Order* table has two columns: id, customer_id
>
> There is a one-to-one relation between these two tables

When I run my code, which is given below, I get the following exception:

```
Hibernate: insert into customer (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into order (customer_id) values (?)
05:02:46,374  WARN [main] JDBCExceptionReporter:233 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
05:02:46,379 ERROR [main] JDBCExceptionReporter:234 - ERROR: syntax error at or near "order"
```

Here is my code. Could someone help to explain the cause of the problem...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {


    public Customer() {
    }

    private long id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "order")

public class Order implements Serializable {
    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    private long id;
    private Customer customer;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
        // setCustomerId(customer.getId());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Customer cm = new Customer();
    cm.setName("John");
    
    Order ord = new Order(cm);

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Transaction transaction = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(ord);
        transaction.commit();
}
    catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` is a SQL keyword. If you can't change the database name, try using:

```
@Table( name = "\"order\"" )
```

But if you're still in development, change table and column names to avoid using SQL keywords.

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY is a SQL keyword.  Perhaps the table name is confusing the parser.  I'd recommend that you rename it and try again.